# add group to /dev/ttyUSB*, Ubuntu 10.02

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I am using a USB to Serial converter on /dev/ttyUSB0 and need the group 
gpib to have access. I'm running Ubuntu 10.02

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

outputs

```
0 crw-rw---- 1 root 188, 0 2013-05-07 13:58 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I don't see a group there...I have written a rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d/80-mdrive.rules

```
KERNEL="ttyUSB*",MODE="0660",GROUP="gpib"
```

When I run the command:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I get an error such as:

```
Cannot open line /dev/ttyUSB0 , Device busy or ....(too fast to read)
Sorry could not find a PTY
```

I'm stuck here...
TIA
wbg

Comment: After restarting, the screen program will connect to my device ONCE...then return the same error.

Comment: interesting fact...I'm actually using PySerial to communicate with a step motor ( device above on /dev/ttyUSB0 ) and PySerial connects with the interface everytime...I don't really need screen but am such a newbie I could still use some help...